# Get ADComputers and filter installed software

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'm very new to Powershell and having trouble figuring out how to piece this together.
I'm looking to get a list of computer names, the OU they're in, and specify the version for a specific program.

I was able to use the Get-WMIObject command for a local machine and filter the results for the specific program i'm looking for.

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property name,version | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "Citrix Receiver Inside"
```

Next, i ran this on our AD Server for the computer name and OU:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "Computer"' | Select Expand Name, DistinguishedName
```

I'm trying to pipe the first Get-WMIObject script to the second 1, but i'm having trouble...

So my end result should be an output of 4 columns: Computer Name, DistinguishedName(OU), Program Name ( All should only be the Citrix Receiver Inside) and the version.

I was planning on using a sub string like command in excel to get the OU name at the end, but if there's a way to get the OU name on it's own in the PS Script then that's even better.

I posted this on the PS subreddit, and they mentioned SCCM/SCOM; I've never used either, if someone can suggest a method with those that would be cool too.

This is a script that was posted on my thread, but i'm still not getting results with this:

```
     $computerList = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "Computer"' | Select-Object -Property DistinguishedName, Name 
 foreach ($computer in $computerList) { 
 Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Product -computername $computer.name | Select-Object -Property name, version | where {$computer.name -eq "Citrix Receiver Inside"}
 }
```

Comment: I haven't been able to get this script working in time, so i took the long and tedious approach instead. Problem solved, but curiosity still growing! If someone can help me correct my script above, or an alternative method to get the desired results ( Computer name, OU, Software name, Version#) it would be really awesome! The documentation i've read online for powershell really don't piece anything together...I can draw a bunch of lines, but how do i make that into a picture????Know what i mean?

Comment: Hi Samal, I've posted an answer below.  Please let me know if you have any questions, and also please try this in your domain.  I think this will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're having a problem because you're running a Where-Object against the wrong value here:

```
 Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Product -computername $computer.name | 
 Select-Object -Property name, version | 
 where {$computer.name -eq "Citrix Receiver Inside"}
```

Get-WMIObject will return a number of bits of information about Win32_Product (installed software), including the Application GUID, Program Name, Program Version and the nickname or caption property.

In your Where-Object command you're saying "Give me the list of software where the **computer's name** is 'Citrix Receiver Inside'.  It is supremely unlikely that you've named a computer that :)

Try this instead:

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Product -computername $computer.name | 
 Select-Object -Property name, version | 
 where {$_.name -eq "Citrix Receiver Inside"}
```

This will give you a list of all of the software named Citrix Receiver Inside.

## Integration

Now, to integrate this into your script as a whole.  You'd like to end up with a list of Computers that have this product and this product only, and then see the comptuername, program name, program version, OU.  One problem you'll have is that some machines will be offline and you won't be able to reach them in a timely manner.

In order to get around this problem (which will cause errors and ugly red text), we'll use a Try/Catch block to try and reach a machine.  If the machine doesn't respond, we'll run the code in the Catch block.

```
try {$product = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Product -computername $computer.name -ErrorAction Stop| 
    Select-Object -Property name, version |
        where {$_.name -eq "Citrix Receiver Inside"} }
catch{$product =[pscustomobject]@{Name="Citrix Receiver Inside";Version="Error"}}
```

The goal here is to make a $product object as well, even if the machine isn't online.  We'll use that in the next step of the script, where we say "If the computer responded, the $product.Version will not equal 'Error', for all of those guys, write out to screen the properties I want".

## Finished Code

```
 $computerList = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "Computer"' | Select-Object -Property DistinguishedName, Name 
foreach ($computer in $computerList) { 

   try {$product = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Product -computername $computer.name -ErrorAction Stop| 
    Select-Object -Property name, version |
        where {$_.name -eq "Citrix Receiver Inside"} }
   catch{$product =[pscustomobject]@{Name="Citrix Receiver Inside";Version="Error"}}

   if ($product.version -ne 'Error'){
    [pscustomobject]@{ComputerName=$computer.Name;
        OU=$computer.DistinguishedName;
        ProgramName=$product.name;
        ProgramVersion=$product.version;
        }
    }
 }
```

**Sample Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a million! This seems to work! I really appreciate your input!